# Bash regex parsing ss output

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep, ss

I'm trying to use a bash regex from a `ss` comand output to extract the name of the application that is using a given port in a function. I have some problems with the regex.

Command to check the data is `ss -tupln`

Example of data to parse (ipv4):

```
tcp    LISTEN   0        10                0.0.0.0:80          0.0.0.0:*    users:(("nc",pid=3474,fd=4))          
tcp    LISTEN   0        10                   [::]:80             [::]:*    users:(("nc",pid=3474,fd=3))
```

In this case I want to extract `nc` which is the name of the program using the port

Example of data to parse (ipv6):

```
tcp   LISTEN 0      511                 *:80              *:*    users:(("apache2",pid=6741,fd=4),("apache2",pid=6740,fd=4),("apache2",pid=6738,fd=4),("apache2",pid=6737,fd=4),("apache2",pid=6736,fd=4),("apache2",pid=6724,fd=4))
```

In this case I want to extract `apache2` which is the name of the program using the port.

I need a general regex valid for both cases. I don't care if it is get using grep or if is done using pure bash regex. My non-working approach:

```
#!/bin/bash

get_name() {
    local regexp="${1}.*[0-9\*]:${2}[[:blank:]]+.*[[:blank:]]+users:\(\(\"(.+)\"\,"

    [[ $(ss -tupln) =~ ${regexp} ]] && process_name="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" 

    echo "${process_name}"
}
get_name "tcp" "80"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use gnu grep:

```
ss -tupln | grep -oP 'tcp\h.*?:80\h.*?\busers:\(\("\K[^"]+(?=")'
```

The pattern matches:

- `tcp\h` Match tcp and a space
- `.*?:80\h` Match as least as possible chars and then `:80` and a space
- `.*?\busers:` Match as least as possible chars and then `users:`
- `\(\("` match `(("`
- `\K[^"]+` Forget what is matched to far (it will not be part of the resulting match)
- `(?=")` Positive lookahead, assert `=` directly to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2G4CBE/1)

Comment: The grep solution worked... the other solution didn't work. Please modify it because I put this as accepted answer to not confuse others. Thanks.

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis I can remove the first part of the answer if you want, and leave only the gnu grep solution. (I did test the `get_name()` function on ubuntu 20.04 and for me it worked out)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` like that:

```
$ ss -tupln | awk -v proto=tcp -v port=80 '$1 == proto && $5 ~ ":" port "$" {split($0, array, "\""); print array[2]}'
apache2
```